# Mouse (Logitech MX Anywhere 3) keeps changing its bluetooth MAC address on every pair

Tags: gnome, manjaro, bluetooth, bluez

The problem:

1. I pair my mouse over bluetooth and everything works fine
2. I turn my mouse off, turn it back on, it does not connect
3. I have to pair the mouse again

The thing i noticed is, that on every re-pair the bluetooth MAC address changes.

This is the output of `bluetoothctl devices` after I paired my mouse a couple of times.

```
    [MX Anywhere 3]# devices 
    Device DC:27:68:47:2A:C7 MX Anywhere 3
    Device DC:27:68:47:2A:C6 MX Anywhere 3
    Device DC:27:68:47:2A:C5 MX Anywhere 3
    Device 68:D6:ED:8B:0A:7F JBL REFLECT MINI NC
    Device C0:4E:71:BD:BC:B1 JBL REFLECT MINI NC-LE
    Device 00:8A:76:2A:8B:AC AirPods Pro
    Device 40:ED:98:1A:3B:7F My BTR5
    Device 00:22:68:C5:CE:9C Wireless Controller
    Device DC:27:68:47:2A:C8 MX Anywhere 3
    Device DC:27:68:47:2A:C9 MX Anywhere 3
    Device DC:27:68:47:2A:CA MX Anywhere 3
```

Notice those `MX Anywhere 3` records. The MAC address goes up by 1.
Why? What causes this? Any ideas?

This is weird, because there was a time, a couple of months ago, where i had no issues with that mouse.

On my Laptop (Thinkpad T14) i run Manjaro with Gnome 41.3.

Comment: You might want to delete the old mouse pairings from the computer, then pair it, and finally set the newest pairing as *trusted*. No clue as to why the MAC address keeps incrementing: maybe it has something to do with the mouse being able to "remember" multiple pairings?

Comment: Already tried that. It simply keeps incrementing on the last MAC address it used. It can connect to 3 different devices. I can switch the device by pressing a button underneath the mouse. However, while pairing and after, it stays on the same device setting and still changes its address.

Comment: I seem to have the same issue, with an old Logitech MX Anywhere 2, started 2 days ago. Someone reported a [similar bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=209745#c19) on the linux kernel bugzilla. I think I had the original issue (I have AX200 bluetooth), but it got fixed. I didn't upgrade the kernel (kernel.org 5.17-rc5 with some patches), but upgraded my system which updated somne bluetooth packages (bluez and others). Did you find any fix?

Comment: No, sadly. It went miraculously away. I didn't do anything to fix it. Instead I now have an issue, where the mouse suddenly stops working but my OS tells me, it is still connected.
This seems to be one of such issues, where some coincidences have to occur for it to happen. The wrong hardware revision, the wrong line of code, the wrong distribution and so on...

Comment: I am having a similar issue. I am using my mouse on Windows and Linux on the same laptop. And I need to pair each time when I switch OS =(